# Cookie Corruption

Tags: browser, cookies, corruption

I have a weird issue with a php redirect script that does the following:

1. Plant a cookie in the user's browser, or read the existing cookie if there is one.
2. Redirect the user to another url (the URL for redirect is a parameter in the original URL, e.g. `http://my.redir.com?url=www.google.com`).
3. **Log the redirect** (time, user-agent, referrer, cookie).

Every once in a while (very rare, one in millions), I see a cookie that got corrupted in the log file.
All cookies have the format `XXXX-XXXX`, when the Xs are a-f or 0-9 (so a valid cookie can be `7bfab3-d8694`). The corrupted cookies have the characters `:` or `/` replacing one of the characters or hyphens, e.g. `7bfa:3-d8694` or `7bfab3/d8694`.

**The question is**, what can cause this? 
Can it be a problem with my script or the server it is running on, or is it more likely to be a problem in the user's browser?

-- more info --

The corrupted cookies I have found had the user-agents:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Sky Broadband; GTB7.1; Sky Broadband; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; Sky Broadband)
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_4_11; en) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.1.3 Safari/533.19.4
```

Comment: Weird! It's almost surely something client side. I guess there's no way to test it if it's that rare. Could be the files getting corrupted while on the client machine. Could also be bad guys just trying to break things.

Comment: Do you realize that such a redirect is a security threat unless you validate the "redirect-to" URLs? E.g. a phisher can send an email with all URLs in it pointing to your domain, while in reality they all lead elsewhere (to hacker's web site). So you need to use some kind of a hash to protect against it...

Comment: It's worth noting that in ASCII, [/ is immediately before 0 and : comes next after 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters).

Comment: @haimg - The security issue was fixed a while ago, but thanks for mentioning. As for your answer below, interesting option, I will check those IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All kinds of "scrapping" robots are badly written, full of bugs. I see similar behavior in my logs, e.g. poor (incorrect) HTML parsers following links incorrectly, "sanitizing" or URL-encoding and URL-decoding stuff in a wrong way, etc.

All this while the "agent" string looks like regular browser. I was freaked by this once, until I noticed how several hundred different pages were hit in a matter of seconds. No chance this is a human being just surfing.

So I suggest you try to see in your logs what else this IP/agent combination was visiting, and if this is a robot, stop worrying about it.

Comment: I hadn't the chance to test this, but since the bounty is over and no new answers came up, here yo go :)

Answer (score 0):

i'd say it's a client side malfunction. but it's hard to tell with all that traffic, if your using for example, setcookie() try using $_SESSION['sess'] = "cookie" instead and see if the problem still occurs.
i hope this helps,
regards.